# SQLite query where selection in the column?

Tags: android, sqlite

How would I write a query that selects where the selection is IN the column? I've only seen it where the column is in the selection like this:

```
String[] names = { "name1", "name2" }; // do whatever is needed first
String query = "SELECT * FROM table"
    + " WHERE name IN (" + makePlaceholders(names.length) + ")";
Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery(query, names);
```

I basically want the opposite of this.
My app is a recipe finding app so there is one column that has a string of ingredients for every entry. I want to be able to select the recipe where the input selection (let's say "chicken rice") was in the string of ingredients ("chicken rice onions...").

Is it possible to do this?

this is what my query looks like now

```
    mCursor = mDb.query(true, SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {COLUMN_ROWID,
            COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_TYPE, COLUMN_INGRED, COLUMN_SPECIAL, COLUMN_DESCRIPT, COLUMN_ALLINGRED, COLUMN_INSTRUCT, COLUMN_IMGPATH},
                    COLUMN_ALLINGRED + "like '%" + inputText + "%'",
            null, null, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your second query not working? You're not doing a "selection in column", it's just a simple text search. But it has many issues (besides performance). What if your ingredients are in a different order? For ex. rice chicken. You probably want to store each ingredient on its own and tokenize inputText and search for all matches of either of the tokens, and prioritize both. Text search is not easy, you'd be much better off offloading this to a service and making calls from the client. You shouldn't have so much offline data anyway, presumably you'll want to update it frequently.

Comment: Sorry, posted the wrong query. But, no it's not working. It isn't doing anything when I try to search. I thought about separating the ingredients but I wasn't exactly sure how I would change the query to search for them. I'm very new to android development so I'm still trying to learn a lot...